# Is there any way to completely turn off an ios device programmatically in xcode?

Tags: ios

I want to make an application that would turn off an iphone at a set time every night;

Comment: Apple doesn't allow a developer to have that much control over a user's iPhone/iPad.

Answer (score 2):

**Absolutely not!** (Unless we are talking about a jailbroken app.)
Apple has a very strict sandboxing approach for third party apps. To access the system, you have to use the provided iOS APIs and none of them offers this kind of control.